# Matcher.find() in Java has an error result when group an regular expression

Tags: java, regex

My code is as follows:

```
 @Test
 public void testMatcher2(){
    String pa2 = "^\\s*(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)\\s*(EQUALS|NOT_EQUALS)\\s*(.*$)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pa2, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Class.fieldNOT_EQUALS'someval'");
    boolean bb = m.find();
    System.out.println(bb);   //#1
    System.out.printf("A=%s. B=%s. C=%s\n", m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3));

    while (m.find()){          //#2
        System.out.println("a");
        String a = m.group(1);
        String b = m.group(2);
        String c = m.group(3);
        System.out.printf("a=%s. b=%s. c=%s\n", a,b,c);
    }
 }
```

and the result is like below:

> true
>   A=Class. B=fieldNOT_. C=EQUALS

My questions are:

1. m.find() returns true when called independently(#1), why does it return false when called in while()(#2)?
2. In this regexp, `Class.fieldNOT_EQUALS'someval'` can be grouped in 2 results (I think):
   `Class/field/NOT_EQUALS/'someval'` (R1, that's what i want) and `Class/fieldNOT_/EQUALS/'someval'` (R2, the result of program), why does the `Matcher` divide the exp into to R2? If I want to get the R1 without changing the exp, how do I get it?

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Try rewriting your second question, as it is hard to understand what you are asking. As for you first question, if you remove your first `find()` you will see that the `find()` within your while returns true. From the javadocs: "Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern" - [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). Your regex will however never yield `true` twice because of your start/end anchors, which forces the full match.

Comment: atomman has the answer to part 1. With part 2, try using lazy quantifier instead of greedy - `(\\w+)\\.(\\w+?)` The fact that you are using a greedy quantifier means that it will try to get everything possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> m.find() return true when called it independently(#1), why it return false called in while()(#2).

See `Matcher`'s Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

> This method [find] starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

As for the second question, the reason why your `Matcher` is dividing it so is greedy matching: the `Matcher` tries to get as much characters as possible when matching each part of the regex. `NOT_` is consumed not by the `(EQUALS|NOT_EQUALS)` part of the expression but the earlier wildcards. Use the reluctant quantifiers (see Javadoc on [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) instead of the greedy ones to fix this.

Comment: This answer would be better if you provided the solution to question 2. How do you do non-greedy matching?

Comment: I was just busy adding it, the answer is in the JavaDoc.

Comment: thank kviiri. i should read the doc more carefully.    
post the differences of this 2 quantifiers:

Greedy quantifiers
X+ one or more times

Reluctant quantifiers
X+? one or more times